# "Template is missing" error in the official RoR tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Please help me figure out this rendering error occuring at *Section 5.3* in the official Ruby On Rails Getting started tutorial (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

```
def create
  render plain: params[:article].inspect
end
```

This code should output a hash of the parameters as mentioned. But it objects to the existence of a corresponding template.

The *Template is missing* error looks like

```
Missing template articles/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Sites/blog/app/views"
```

Comment: Hi,
Are you sure you update (restart?..) the server?.. This example should work.

Comment: did you re-submit the form?

Comment: The example should work. What if you append `and return` to the render call? => `render plain: params[:article].inspect and return`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
render text:
```

intead of

```
render plain:
```

?

Comment: text: is what I need to do.  Rails 4.0.0, Ruby 2.0.0p247.

Answer (score 5):

`plain` option was added in `Rails 4.1`. The Rails guide is for that version. I am guessing that your Rails version is lower than that. So, rails is ignoring this option and looking for a template named articles/create as you are in ArticlesController#create action. Obviously, the template doesn't exist so you get the error Template is missing.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I had 4.0.2 installed. Accepting the earlier answer.